# Batch script to take first & second part of folder name and create new folders from them

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Any wizards out there that can help with this?
I have some music folders labelled like this "Taylor Swift - 1989" etc with just the music files and folder image in the one folder.

I need help with a batch script that takes the first part of a folder name ie (Taylor Swift) and creates a new folder with that part of the name, then moves the original folder into it, renaming it as the second part of the folder name ie (1989)

So an example is: A folder with name of "taylor swift - 1989" gets a new folder made by delimiting the "-", would just become "taylor swift" and then have the original folder moved & re-named as the subfolder just labelled "1989" and all the music files would be in that folder.

I have tried this script, but I can't work out how to switch the names and folders, all the movement seems correct.

```
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in ("* - *") do 2>nul (

     echo\ & set "_Folder=%%~i"
     echo\Folder found: ...\!_Folder:*\=!
     cd /d "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!\." ) && 2>nul ( 
     echo\Folder "!_Folder:*- =!" exists... & cd.. ) || 2>nul (
     echo\Folder: ...\!_Folder:*- =! does not exist, creating...
     mkdir "%~dp0!_Folder:*- =!" & echo\Moving file ..\!_Folder:*- =! to folder !_Folder:*- =! 
     move "%%~fi" "%CD%\!_Folder:*- =!" && echo\Moving file "%%~nxi" to folder "..\!_Folder:*- =!".. 
     
    ) 
    )
    
echo\Finished & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -t 60 & endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

Comment: Is batch script required? This is very easy to do with powershell.

Comment: Also, consider creating 2 new folders, move everything, then delete the old. Probably easier to do in batch.

Comment: I really like solving dos batch challenges, just for the sake of solving them. But this would be so much easier using (almost) any other scripting language. Powershell, Python, even VBScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f delims^= %%i in =;(' dir /a:-a /b "* - *"
    ');= do for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*delims^=-^" %%G in =;(`
         set /p "'=%%~nxi"^<nul `);= do call %:^) "%%~G" "%%~H" "%%~dpnxi"

%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" =;(
     set "_dir=%~1" & set "_sub=%~2"
     call rename "%~3" "%%_sub:~1%%"
     call mkdir "%cd%\%%_dir:~0,-1%%"
     call move "%%_sub:~1%%" "%%_dir:~0,-1%%" 
     );= & exit /b
```

---

**1.** List your folders by filtering the occurrences with **<kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>** in a loop:

```bash
for /f delims^= %%i in (' dir /a:-a /b "* - *" ') do ....
```

**2.** Straight to a second loop, separate the occurrences of the strings in the folder name ***occurs before*** **"-"** ***occurs after*** and get the full path folder:

---

```bash
 for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*delims^=-^" %%G in (`set /p "'=%%~nxi"^<nul `) do ... "%%~G" "%%~H" "%%~dpnxi"
```

---

**3.** call a label to handle the substrings necessary to compose the subfolder names for the commands to come

---

```bash
 for /f ... (`...`) do call %:^) "%%~G" "%%~H" "%%~dpnxi"
```

---

**4.** Inside the function, use set variable=susbtrings to compose folder names and for other commands:

```bash
@echo off

...
...
...
 
%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" =;(
     set "_dir=%~1" & set "_sub=%~2"
        ...      "%~3" "%%_sub:~1%%"
        ...      "%cd%\%%_dir:~0,-1%%"
        ...      "%%_sub:~1%%" "%%_dir:~0,-1%%" 
     );= & exit /b
```

---

**5.** Take the name "`numeric`", remove space before the name "`artists`" and after "`year`", that done, rename the current folder to the year, create the folder for the name and then move the year folder inside from the `artist` folder:

```bash
     call rename "%~3" "%%_sub:~1%%"
     call mkdir "%cd%\%%_dir:~0,-1%%"
     call move "%%_sub:~1%%" "%%_dir:~0,-1%%"
```

---

- Some further reading:
- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Ren /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

  - [`For Loop /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/Move.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`%Varible:String=Manipulation%`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

Comment: lo-ol.. Amazing.. Thankyou soo much.. soo much more to learn.. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [Barend](https://superuser.com/a/1817998/167207)!

This worked, as you said, I had to extend it to incorporate longer artist and album names.

I wasn't exactly sure what I was doing, but a bit of trial and error sees this as the end result

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-20" %%a in (`dir /A:D /B *-*`) do (
    set full=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%b==- set name=%%a & set year=%%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%c==- set name=%%a %%b & set year=%%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%d==- set name=%%a %%b %%c & set year=%%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%e==- set name=%%a %%b %%c %%d & set year=%%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%f==- set name=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e & set year=%%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%g==- set name=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f & set year=%%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    if %%h==- set name=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g & set year=%%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p
    
    if not exist "!name!" mkdir "!name!"
    rename "!full!" "!year!"
    move "!year!" "!name!"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I thought about it some more and came up with the following. Please don't ask for more, other languages are really more suitable to do something like this.

I haven't tested extensively, I'll leave that up to you. This example should get you going.

```dos
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-5" %%a in (`dir /A:D /B *-*`) do (
    set full=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e
    if %%b==- set name=%%a & set year=%%c %%d %%e
    if %%c==- set name=%%a %%b & set year=%%d %%e
    if %%d==- set name=%%a %%b %%d & set year=%%e
    
    if not exist "!name!" mkdir "!name!"
    rename "!full!" "!year!"
    move "!year!" "!name!"
)
```

This will loop over all folders that have a dash in their name, and no extension. I assume a maximum of 5 parts for the folder name, but you can easily extend that yourself. Each part should be separated from other parts by a single space. Folder names should not begin or end with a dash, or have more than one dash.